# how to use an element taken from array1 as index to array2?

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-arrays

THIS IS THE FUNCTION:I want to take y as index to array s0 and s1. how doI do that? what is wrong in this code?

```py
def dynamicArray(n, queries):
    # Write your code here
    lastAnswer=0
    s0=[]
    s1=[]
    l=len(queries)
    for i in range(l):
        qtype=queries[i][0]
        x=queries[i][1]
        y=queries[i][2]
        if qtype==1:
            if ((x^lastAnswer)%2==0):
                s0.append(y)
            elif ((x^lastAnswer)%2==1):
                s1.append(y)
        if qtype==0:
            if ((x^lastAnswer)%2==0):
                return lastAnswer==s0[y]
            elif ((x^lastAnswer)%2==1):
                return lastAnswer==s1[y]
```

Comment: what's `x^lastAnswer` supposed to do? if it's power use `**` operator for power in python. and if you are checking for %2 then the first operator has to be integer. checking for modulo with a float causes an error. If power if integer then only check for x%2, integer power of odd is odd, and that of even is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're misunderstanding '^' operator. I am assunimg you're thinking it does exponentiation, where it's in fact used to do **Binary(XOR)** operation. Python uses `**` for exponentiation.

See this:

```
Binary XOR(^)

It performs bit by bit XOR(exclusive-OR) on the two values. Here, XOR-ing 10(2) and 11(3) results in 01(1).

>>> 2^3
```

So what you need to do is change the operator as follows and you can then use the index as elements in the array.

```
def dynamicArray(n, queries):
    # Write your code here
    lastAnswer=0
    s0=[]
    s1=[]
    l=len(queries)
    for i in range(l):
        qtype=queries[i][0]
        x=queries[i][1]
        y=queries[i][2]
        if qtype==1:
            if ((x**lastAnswer)%2==0):
                s0.append(y)
            elif ((x**lastAnswer)%2==1):
                s1.append(y)
        if qtype==0:
            if ((x**lastAnswer)%2==0):
                return lastAnswer==s0[y]
            elif ((x**lastAnswer)%2==1):
                return lastAnswer==s1[y]
```